# Using data from txt file to make a plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a file with float numbers( -1.22070E-02   -7.32420E-02 ) on two columns.
I want to read them and make a plot. Something like the examples here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/signal-generation-and-visualization.html.
After searching this is my code:

```
fid = fopen('sample_b.txt', 'r');
a = fscanf(fid, '%f %f', [2 inf]);
simin = a';
plot(simin(:,1),simin(:,2));
fclose(fid);
```

But this is the plot I get:

[image]

And when I display simin using 'disp(simin)' I see:

```
81.4724   90.5792
12.6987   91.3376
63.2359    9.7540
27.8498   54.6882
```

I do not understand why my program uses these 8 numbers. My file contains many numbers, but the first 8 are these:

```
    -1.22070E-02   -7.32420E-02
    1.22070E-02   0.197750
    4.88280E-03    9.27730E-02
    -4.39450E-02    3.41800E-02
```

If I use 'plot(a(:,1),a(:,2));' the plot is just a line.

Edit: my data represents and EEG signal.

Comment: Could be an encoding issue? Your code works for me! Note that `fscanf(fid, '%f %f', [2 inf]);` and `a = fscanf(fid, '%f', [2 inf]);` produce the same result.

Comment: Like Cris says, it should work fine. Are you sure that your data is correct? I'm not sure why you introduce `simin` when you can `plot(a(1,:),a(2,:))`.

Comment: You **transposed** `a` to define `simin`, however, in plotting you treated the same although rows and columns are changed.